# Compare a Color Code to a Color

Tags: java

```
package BotMenu;

import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class BotClass {

    public static void main(String[] Args){

        try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            Color color = robot.getPixelColor(20, 20);

            robot.mouseMove(20, 20);
            System.out.println("The code is   = " + color.getRGB());



        } catch (AWTException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

I'm finding a pixel on my screen, but how can I save `PixelColor` in a variable so I can do a `if` statement on it?

For example:

`if ColorStuff = -239293 then stop`

Comment: What do you mean by **save the PixelColor in a variable after os**? Do you mean saving the variable for usage outside of the try/catch block?

Comment: Just in the try and catch

Comment: Also, [How do I use a variable outside of a try/catch?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16613979/5475891) may be relevant

Comment: I just wanna do so if color = something then i can like move the mouse to anothre coordinate

Comment: **in the try and catch**, is `Color color = ...` not in the try block?  You can use operations on your `color` variable, it doesn't go away after using `color.getRGB()`

Comment: How will you do a if statement on it?

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to compare. `if(color.equals(Color.BLACK))` will check if it's black, `if(color.equals(new Color(191, 127, 0))` will check if it's a certain shade of orange, `if(color.getRGB() == 16776960)` will check if it's yellow (or use `0xFFFF00`)

Comment: if(color.getRGB() == 16776960) Thats what i needed thanks phflack

Comment: how do i end the thread?

Comment: The thread executing main will end once your main method ends and when all sub-threads (you have none) have ended (*don't worry about the threads on something this small*)

Answer (score 1):

Comparing a Color object to an int value has two straightforward approaches

**A. Convert the Color to an int**

```
Color c = new Color(255, 255, 0); //solid yellow
int i = 0xFFFFFF00; //int representation of solid yellow
if(c.getRGB() == i)
    System.out.println("yellow is yellow");
```

**B. Convert the int to a Color**

```
Color c = new Color(255, 0, 0, 127); //transparent red
int i = 0x7FFF0000; //int representation of transparent red
if(c.equals(new Color(i, true))) //the boolean argument indicates an alpha value
    System.out.println("red is very red");
```

Colors are stored in the format **AARRGGBB** in hexadecimal, Alpha Red Green Blue